# Set up a .app custom domain on a heroku app

Tags: domain-name, heroku

I have added a custom domain on my heroku app

```
heroku domains:add www.mydomain.app
```

Now I run

```
heroku domains
```

and getting a DNS Target for my domain

On the next step I am trying to add the Target DNS on my domain registration service and I am getting an error.

```
The .app domain names require 2 minimum nameservers.
```

Is it possible to set a second dns target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are changing the wrong settings on your domain registration service. Based on the error message, you are trying to change the *nameservers* for the entire domain – that is, servers which hold all information about your domain and its subdomains. This is **not** where Heroku's addresses go, and they even explicitly say as much [in "custom domains" documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains):

> Heroku does not provide a domain registration service (for registering a custom domain name) or a DNS provider service (for hosting the DNS servers that point your custom domain name to your app).

So you need to keep the "nameserver" settings where they currently are (I assume that your registrar provides free DNS hosting, because nearly all of them do).

Instead, find the "record management" or "subdomains" area at your registrar (which lists a table of domains/subdomains and associated addresses), and change just the specific (sub)domain's A/AAAA/CNAME records to point at Heroku.